# How do I remove or disable WPF Window Report Designer Properties

Tags: c#, wpf, syncfusion, report-designer

Good morning Devs;

I have a Syncfusion Report Designer on a WPF Window. The Syncfusion Report Designer is similar to the SSRS and Windows Forms Report Designers.

I am creating a template designer application and want to give the user limited functionality when it comes to the actual report and the body parts of the report, related to their properties.

When you have the properties window open and click on the report part of the report, the report properties are displayed, as per image 1.

[image]

When you click on the body of the report, the body properties are displayed as per image 2.

[image]

When you click on any of the images in the report, in this case only one image, the selected image properties are displayed as per image 3.

[image]

All good.

But wanting to limit the user on the body and the report properties, is there any way I can "clear" the properties window when the user selects either the body or the report? I know I can hide (close) the properties window when they select either the body or the report, but the user has the functionality to click a button and open the properties window, and hide/show will have too much of an inconsistency in the user experience. Somehow I need to hook into the properties window and "clear" or "lock" the properties. How do I do that?

Comment: I don't know Syncfusion, but i think that, if the control does not allow you to set what is editable or not, you can try to retemplate the properties window starting from its default one. But it can easly go  hard to do...

Comment: Having worked with SSRS and Windows Report Designer, I can tell you they are similar. The namespaces and constructors differ slightly but overall they are similar. If someone could even give me a solution or an idea on either the SSRS or Windows Report Designers that would be great, I could alter it to my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Syncfusion ReportDesigner don’t have a support to restrict the property grid selected element based on your need. So, you can created a support ticket with Syncfusion [Direct-Trac](https://www.syncfusion.com/support/directtrac/incidents/newincident) for the feature requirement